# Converting radial brightness profile to 2D intensity distribution

Tags: astropy, healpy

I have 2-column tables representing the light intensity distribution of a source as a function of its angular radius. These tables were obtained by digitizing the first plot and third plot [in this figure](https://cfn-live-content-bucket-iop-org.s3.amazonaws.com/journals/0004-637X/801/2/74/revision1/apj508296f6_lr.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAYDKQL6LTV7YY2HIK&Expires=1649102190&Signature=4Nc6C4I9inWEIO35jDOcGbS5CCc%3D). The x-aix is the angular radius of the two sources. The y-axis is the intensity of the sources.

Now I want to convert the 1D distributions to 2D distributions as function of longitude and latitude. Also, I want to draw the distributions as healpy maps. Can someone please tell me how this conversion can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hp.ang2pix(nside, lon, lat, lonlat=True)` to go from longitude and latitude to a pixel index in a HEALPix map.

Then you can put the value of the intensity in that location in the array.

A full tutorial notebook is available here:

https://gist.github.com/zonca/680c68c3d60697eb0cb669cf1b41c324

It is linked from the docs:

https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other_tutorials.html#pixelization